# Draw heatmap between two tensors

Tags: tensorflow

I have 2 tensors of size [None, 200] and want to draw heatmap between these two. Without converting tensors to a list, is it possible? if yes, please point to some reference code.

Comment: I think converting to numpy would be necessary. Also, what do you mean by "heatmap between two tensors"? You want to subtract one from another and draw a heatmap?

Comment: I want to visualize how each part of one tensor is related to other tensors'

Comment: Does that mean stacking them into a [2, 200] array and visualizing each value?

Comment: kind of... but not stacking [2,200] ... one-[1,200] horizontal,, and [1,200] vertical at y axis

Answer (score 1):

Let's take we have two tensors as:

```
x1 = tf.random.uniform((1,10),minval=0,maxval=10,dtype=tf.int32)
y1 = tf.random.uniform((1,10),minval=0,maxval=10,dtype=tf.int32)
```

Now we want a heatmap to compare these tensors of how much their values are different.

```
x2 = tf.broadcast_to(x1, [x1.shape[1], x1.shape[1]])
y2 = tf.broadcast_to(tf.transpose(y1),(y1.shape[1],y1.shape[1]))
# It depends on your objective to select which operation you want to apply to these tensors. 
# In this example we subtract them to calculate their difference like MAE function. 
heatmap=tf.abs((y2-x2)) 
#heatmap = tf.reduce_mean(heatmap, axis=-1) #you may get mean if you have more than one axis
plt.matshow(heatmap)
x1 = x1.numpy().squeeze().tolist()
y1 = y1.numpy().squeeze().tolist()
plt.xticks(range(len(x1)),x1)
plt.yticks(range(len(y1)),y1)
plt.show()
```

The output is like this, which darker pixels shows less difference  and brighter ones shows more difference:

[image: subtract_heatmap]

If you don't want to use any numpy or list at all, you can try this:

```
x2 = tf.broadcast_to(x1, [x1.shape[1], x1.shape[1]])
y2 = tf.broadcast_to(tf.transpose(y1),(y1.shape[1],y1.shape[1]))
heatmap=tf.abs((y2-x2)) 
plt.matshow(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

Comment: hi kaveh.. thanks for looking into it. by this statement x2 = np.array(..) we are converting tensor to array/list .. is there some other way without this statement

Comment: You can remove it. remove np.array() and let tf.broadcast remain. Still you can plot heatmap. Updated my answer.

Comment: I have also added 4 last lines for a better intuition of plot. It is not necessary and they also can be removed.